# Divide a list into sublists such that difference between any 2 elements in a sublist should not exceed k

Tags: python

Can anyone provide an approach for this:

Divide a list into sublists such that the absolute difference between any 2 elements in a sublist should not exceed a 'k' value.sublists can be formed irrespective of order. A sublist can be of any number of elements. The number of sublists should be minimal

```
Example:
arr=[1,5,4,6,8,9,2]
k=3

sublists generated are [[2,1],[5,4,6],[8,9]]

Example 2:
arr=[1,13,6,8,9,3,5]
k=4

sublists generated are [[1,3,5],[6,8],[13,9]]
```

We need to return the minimal number of sublist where the difference between 2 lists must not exceed k. an element can be in only 1 sublist

Comment: I would sort the list, then create and fill the sublist if value_n+1 - value_n does not exceed k. If the difference exceed k, then start a new sublist with the value_n+1.

Comment: @LittlePanic404 hey I tried this but sometimes a sublist will be made of only 1 element.then how would difference be calculated

Comment: When it happens, pick the last item from the previous sublist. If it makes it a one item sublist, pick from the previous one and so on.

Comment: @CodewithSV is it a problem to have a sublist of one element ? You say sublist can have any number of elements.

Comment: the threshold condition is unclear, is it '<k' or '<=k'? The first example seems to be '<' and the second '<='

Comment: @mozway it can be equal to k as well

Comment: OK, then you would need to use `<=` in my answer and I think your first example might need an update

Comment: @LittlePanic404 if a sublist has 1 element how can we calculate difference. so it must be atleast 2 elements right?

Comment: @CodewithSV let's say the sorted list is [1,10,20], k=2. 10-1 >k, you create sublist [1] and move to next element in list. 10-20>k, you get [[1],[10]]. etc. There is no problem, since you calculate the difference from the list and not the sublist. It is independent of the sublist size.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of ambiguity around question. It was Amazon SDE question .

Comment: If you consider an `<=` threshold, why would the 8 in `[1,5,4,6,8,9,2]` not cluster with `[5,4,6]`?

Comment: The question as it is is not clear enough. Should all sublists contain a least 2 items? If this is the case, is it guaranteed that the input data provided will allow this constraint to be satisfied? Should the number of sublists be minimal, or is any solution accepted? ...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille the number of sublists should be minimal

Comment: @CodewithSV every time someone asks question you skip many of the questions ;) please be explicit, provide many examples and all the rules for your problem

Comment: Ok let me be clear. We need to return the minimal number of sublist where the difference between 2 lists must not exceed k. an element can be in only 1 sublist. I hope its clear now

Comment: @CodewithSV I believe this is what [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965757/16343464) is doing, please provide a counter example if you think this is incorrect. NB. I imagine "*difference between 2 lists*" actually means "*difference between **any two items** in the sublists*".

Answer (score 0):

```py
# easier version
arr = sorted(arr)
lst = []
sublist = [arr.pop(0)]
while len(arr) > 0:
    item = arr.pop(0)
    if item - sublist[0] >= k:
        lst.append(sublist)
        sublist = [item]
    else:
        sublist.append(item)
lst.append(sublist)
print(lst)

# shorter version
arr = sorted(arr)
lst = [[arr.pop(0)]]
while len(arr) > 0:
    item = arr.pop(0)
    lst.append([item]) if item - lst[-1][0] >= k else lst[-1].append(item)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks, Your code generates [9] and [13] as 2 sublists but we need [9,13] as in example 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using the sorted array:

*NB. I used a strict threshold here, update the code to use "<=" if equality is accepted.*

```
def split(arr, k):
    out = []
    for i in sorted(arr):
        if not out:
            out = [[i]]
            continue
        if out[-1] and i-out[-1][0] < k:  # use <= to accept equality
            out[-1].append(i)
        else:
            out.append([i])
    return out
```

example:

```
split([1,5,4,6,8,9,2], 3)
# [[1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9]]

split([1,13,6,8,9,3,5], 4)
# [[1, 3], [5, 6, 8], [9], [13]]
```

Comment: first example seems perfect but in second , how can we calculate difference if a sublist of only 1 element.

Comment: If I understand your question: as the values are sorted, you only need to compare to the first item of each sublist. Or maybe this isn't the question? How would you split `[1,2,3, 100]`?

Comment: suppose if my array is [1,5,4,7,8] and k is 3 I would need [1,4],[5,7,8] I hope u understood

Comment: @CodewithSV if you use my code with '<=', this is what you'll get. What should be the ouput for `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and `k=3`?

Comment: I tried with ur list we will get 1 element as seperate subset element which is strange

Comment: You don't have it if you use '<=', check again your initial examples, the two provided use a different logic

Answer (score 0):

```
def ex(arr, k):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    new_lst = []
    sub_lst = [arr[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] - sub_lst[0] < k:
            sub_lst.append(arr[i])
        else:
            new_lst.append(sub_lst)
            sub_lst = [arr[i]]
    new_lst.append(sub_lst)
    return new_lst


arr = [1, 13, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5]
k = 4
print(ex(arr, k))
```

Little explanation:
We are sorting the list. Than we check for the first element the matching items. Because the list is sorted, they will be right next to him in the list. If the next element isnt matching, we can "close" this sub_lst, append it to the new_lst, and than initialize the sub_lst with the next item. Once we finished, we need to append sub_lst to new_lst because we didn't get in the if statement there.

Comment: Thanks but as u can see in example 2 our sublist should [9,13] but ur code generates [9],[13] that is 2 seperate sublists. Can u check again?

Comment: Its like putting 9 in the left sublist in your example. As far as I understand its still meet the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
import random                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                              
k=10                                                                                                                                                                                          
random.seed(10)                                                                                                                                                                               
randomList = []                                                                                                                                                                               
listOfSublist = []                                                                                                                                                                            
for i in range(0,10):                                                                                                                                                                         
    n = random.randint(1,100)                                                                                                                                                                 
    randomList.append(n)
print(randomList)   
# uncomment this to test with the example
# randomList = [1,13,6,8,9,3,5]
# k = 4                                                                                                                                             
randomList.sort()                                                                                                                                                                             
print(randomList)                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                              
n = 0                                                                                                                                                                                         
for i in range(len(randomList)-1):                                                                                                                                                            
    if randomList[i+1] - randomList[n] >= k: # when difference exceed k, create sublist                                                                                                        
        listOfSublist.append( randomList[n:i+1])                                                                                                                                              
        n=i+1                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                              
listOfSublist.append( randomList[n:len(randomList)]) # handle the end of the list                                                                                                                                          
print(listOfSublist)
```

I believe there is a solution without sorting, and you can improve this by deleting the numbers you pick from randomList at each step, in case memory is an issue.

output:

```
[74, 5, 55, 62, 74, 2, 27, 60, 63, 36]
[2, 5, 27, 36, 55, 60, 62, 63, 74, 74]
[[2, 5], [27, 36], [55, 60, 62, 63], [74, 74]]
```

Comment: Thanks , I have tried ur code with input with this list [1,13,6,8,9,3,5] and got [[1], [13, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5]]

Comment: @CodewithSV I think you did a mistake, the list you obtain is not sorted. I added the lines to test with your example, I got [[1, 3, 5], [6, 8, 9], [13]] which is correct to me. I also changed the equality test according to your comments (>=k instead of >k).

Comment: what u got when u put >k?

Comment: @CodewithSV [[1, 3, 5], [6, 8, 9], [13]] with >k, [[1, 3], [5, 6, 8], [9], [13]] with >=k. k=4.

Comment: but we need to get [[1,3,5],[6,8],[13,9]] how is it possible?

Comment: Tell explicitly what are the rules, one by one, of your problem. It's unclear. It looks like there are more than one rule. My code solve the following rule: "the absolute difference between any 2 elements in a sublist should not exceed a 'k' value." (or equal to k value).

9-6=3 <k so it belong the sublist [5,6,8,9]. 5-1=4=k so it does not belong to [1,3,5] but to [5,6,8,9].

Comment: 1.We need to return the minimal number of sublists where the difference between 2 elements must not exceed k. an element can be in only 1 sublist       2. difference between 2 elements in list can be less or equal to k.

Comment: @CodewithSV  In rule one, it's between two element in a sublist ? In rule two, it is between sublist not list right ? Just to be sure.

Comment: difference bteween 2 elements in sublist should not exceed k

Comment: @CodewithSV and rule 2? You want to compare two adjacent sublist ?

Comment: no. comparing elements in sublist such that their difference should not exceed k. example:   [2,3,5] in this elements in this sublist doesnt exceed k of 3. difference can be equal to k too

Comment: It's what my code does then.

Comment: we need to return minimal number of substrings .

Comment: again, with k=4, 13-9=4=k, so you can't do a sublist made of [9,13] without breaking the rule.