# How to merge values in a dictionary depending on range

Tags: python, dictionary, range, mapping, key-value

I want to merge values depending on their key

```py
d1 = {"300":["index1","index2"],"301":["index9","index10"],"400":["index12","index13"]
```

I want to merge the values for the keys that are within the range of 10 so like 300 merge with 301 because 301 is bigger than 300 by 1 but 301 wont go with 400 because 400 is bigger than both of them over 10 but if we also had 410 we would merge it with 400 because its exactly 10 from the 400 so anything less than or equal to 10 that range everything in it gets merged

This post makes no sense and I dont know how to explain it

Comment: What if there are 301, 310, 320 in d1? Should all three be merged, none of them or should there be two merges (once 300 and 310 and once 310 and 320)? This problem would disappear if you would merge all values with keys within the same fixed intervals of 10, however I doubt that this is desired, as then e.g. 299 and 301 would not be merged for intervals with boundaries divisible by 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    from itertools import chain
    
    d1 = {"300":["index1","index2"],"301":["index9","index10"],"400":["index12","index13"], "410":["index14","index15"]}
    # the split function is found here. [split function][1]
    def split(arr, k):
        arr = [int(e) for e in arr]
        out = []
        for i in sorted(arr):
            if not out:
                out = [[i]]
                continue
            if out[-1] and i-out[-1][0] <= k:  # use <= to accept equality
                out[-1].append(i)
            else:
                out.append([i])
        return out
    
    d = {}
    # for each sublist of divided keys find the corresponding values, and save to a new dictionary 
    for lst in split(d1,10):
        d[' '.join(map(str,lst))] = list(chain(*[d1.get(str(k)) for k in lst]))
    
    print(d)
    
    {'300 301': ['index1', 'index2', 'index9', 'index10'], '400 410': ['index12', 'index13', 'index14', 'index15']}


  [1]: https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965420/divide-a-list-into-sublists-such-that-difference-between-any-2-elements-in-a-sub
```

Comment: is there a way to have the merge key only 1 of them like it can be anyone of them so like 300:index1,index2,index9,index10

Comment: @Zen35X. Yes, you just can change the key of the new dictionary as follows d[str(lst[0])] = list(chain(*[d1.get(str(k)) for k in lst])) The result will be  {'300': ['index1', 'index2', 'index9', 'index10'], '400': ['index12', 'index13', 'index14', 'index15']}